# Getting Access Denied from LinkedIn -C# Web API implementation

Tags: linkedin-api

My Implementation leans on `Owin.Security.Providers.LinkedIn`
I am getting access denied error after getting the Authorization Code successfully from
`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization`

The weird thing occurs when I take this Authorization Code into postman and try to get an access token
from here:
`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken`
This request from Postman responds successfully with the Access Token that I need.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Literally *NO* idea!